# Delphi and c++ struct

Tags: c++, delphi

I have the following C++ function that exports a struct with a `char*` field in it, but the string value is not as expected when used in Delphi, although it is null-terminated.

```cpp
typedef struct _MyStruct{
    char* name;
    // other fields
}MyStruct,*PMyStruct;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl MyTestStr(PMyStruct _PMyStruct)
{
    std::string str = "string";
    std::vector<char> cstr(str.begin(), str.end);
    cstr.push_back('\0');//null-terminated
    _PMyStruct->name = cstr.data();    
}
```

```pascal
type
  PMyStruct = ^MyStruct;
  MyStruct= record
    name : PAnsiChar;
        // other fields
  end;

procedure MyTestStr(_PMyStruct: PMyStruct); cdecl; external 'mytest.dll' name 'MyTestStr';    

procedure TestMyRec();
var
  _MyStruct: MyStruct;
begin
  MyTestStr(@_MyStruct); 
  showmessage(_MyStruct.name);
  // here the result is just 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY' not 'string'
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: @MartynA i'm using the `Tokyo` version .

Answer (score 1):

`_PMyStruct->name=cstr.data();` just makes pointer onto string body. But after function call **local object** `std::string` should be disposed. So you have got pointer to some memory address with unpredictable contents, this might cause AV if memory does not belong to application more.

Seems you have to allocate memory and call function that **copies** needed data into this memory address. Free this memory when needed.

Comment: thank you , you mean using `new` ... `delete` in my c++ part and get-rid of the `vector` ?

Comment: @Sdean You will still need to co-ordinate when the memory is released if you do that.

Comment: Only one side must be responsible for memory allocation  and freeing - or dll  - in this case you have to provide additional function to free memory, -or application - imho better option. Note that many of WinAPI functions should be called twice - 1) to determine memory size and 2) real work with preallocated memory buffer

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of `_MyStruct::name` to `const char *`, and just assign the literal to it.

Note that names starting `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation, so your whole program has undefined behaviour.

You don't need to `typedef struct`.

```
struct MyStruct
{ 
    const char* name; // mutable pointer to constant char(s)
    // other fields
};

using PMyStruct = * MyStruct;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl void MyTestStr(PMyStruct pMyStruct)
{
    pMyStruct->name = "string";
}
```

In the general case, it is inadvisable to pass owning pointers across dll boundaries. Instead the [caller should allocate](http://mc-computing.com/Languages/Delphi/Buffers.html), and the function copy into that allocation. This is the pattern used across the Win32Api. You either return the size, or take `int *` parameters to write the sizes into

C++ Dll

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl void MyTestStr(PMyStruct pMyStruct = nullptr, int * firstname_size = nullptr, int * lastname_size = nullptr)
{
    if (pMyStruct)
    {
        std::strncpy(pMyStruct->firstname, "string", pMyStruct->firstname_len);
        std::strncpy(pMyStruct->lastname, "other string", pMyStruct->lastname_len);
    }
    if (firstname_size) { *firstname_size = 7; }
    if (lastname_size) { *lastname_size = 13; }
}
```

Delphi exe

```
type
  PInteger = ^Integer;
  PMyStruct = ^MyStruct;
  MyStruct= record
    firstname : PAnsiChar;
    firstname_len : Integer;
    lastname : PAnsiChar;
    lastname_len : Integer;
    // other fields
  end;

procedure MyTestStr(pMyStruct: PMyStruct; firstname_len : PInteger; lastname_len : PInteger); cdecl; external 'mytest.dll' name 'MyTestStr';   

procedure TestMyRec();
var
  myStruct: MyStruct;
begin
// If you don't know how much memory you will need, you have to ask
  MyTestStr(nil, @myStruct.firstname_len, @myStruct.lastname_len); 
  GetMem(myStruct.firstname, myStruct.firstname_len);
  GetMem(myStruct.lastname, myStruct.lastname_len);

  MyTestStr(@myStruct); 

  // Use myStruct

  FreeMem(myStruct.firstname);
  FreeMem(myStruct.lastname);
end;
```

Comment: thank you , but what about the `null-termination` , will my delphi part read it as 'string' ?

Comment: string literals are null terminated

Comment: indeed i use the **vector** to convert an `std::string` into `char*`

Comment: `std::string` has a member `data()` that returns a null terminated `char *`. It also has a member `c_str()` that returns a null terminated `const char *`. But the `std::string` has to outlast the usage on the Delphi side in either case

Comment: thank you but what if i've other fields : `struct MyStruct
{ 
    char * const name;
    int name_len;
   char * const lastname;
   int lastname_len;
    // other fields
};`
cause i see that `MyTestStr` function now returns the length of the string

Comment: You either return both sizes, or take "out" parameters

Comment: consider this : `inline char* string_as_array(std::string* str) {
        return str->empty() ? nullptr : &*str->begin();
    }`
How could i add a null-termination to the result?

Comment: @Sdean it already is null terminated. and you can just use [`str.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: Also: please don't pass `nullptr` when you mean "empty collection"

Comment: so many thanks , but still get `ÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝ`
in my delphi side

Comment: Make sure that the `std::string`s are still alive while the Delphi code uses that pointer. Values local to `MyTestStr` cease to exist at the end of that method

Comment: Are you allocating space in the Delphi caller?

Comment: this works : `inline char* string_as_array_with_zero_term(std::string str) {
        const auto ca = new char[str.size() + 1];
        memcpy(ca, str.c_str(), str.size());
        ca[str.size()] = '\0';
        return ca;
    }` , But i've to handle it with `free` each time

Comment: Don't allocate anything on the C++ side. Allocate on the Delphi side, pass a pointer to that allocation, then `memcpy` into it.

Comment: Hmmm... `std::strncpy(pMyStruct->firstname, "string", pMyStruct->firstname_len);` You are copying data to what address, actually? I don't see you allocating a buffer to contain the string. Why not `char firstname[256];`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The buffer is provided by the caller. They set both `firstname` and `firstname_len`

Comment: @Caleth: sdean had written a comment replying to me (but has obviously deleted it again) that he was setting up buffers for firstname, etc. anyway. This did not show in his question, so I wrote what I wrote.